# Wrong behavior of xargs

Tags: find, xargs

I was trying to solve [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/70993/how-to-count-recursively-for-the-number-of-files-in-several-directories) issue using `find` + `xargs` but I stuck with another issue

I am try to increasing `a` count using `((a++))` but not working . I have tried couple of combination of counting a value eg. `let a++` `a=$[ $a + 1]` and so on..

See below Output

```
rax@ubuntu:~# find ./test/ -mindepth 1 | xargs -I{} -n1 bash -xc "((a++)) ; echo $a {}"
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 ./test/abc1
0 ./test/abc1
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 ./test/abc1/abc
0 ./test/abc1/abc
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 ./test/abc2
0 ./test/abc2
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 ./test/abc3
0 ./test/abc3
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 ./test/abcparent
0 ./test/abcparent
```

EDIT :- 
xargs did all in same shell

eg. with pid

```
rax@ubuntu:~# a=0
rax@ubuntu:~# find ./test/ -mindepth 1 | xargs -L2 -I{}  bash -xc "echo $a {} ;((a++)) ; echo $a $$"
+ echo 0 ./test/abc1
0 ./test/abc1
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 1314
0 1314
+ echo 0 ./test/abc1/abc
0 ./test/abc1/abc
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 1314
0 1314
+ echo 0 ./test/abc2
0 ./test/abc2
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 1314
0 1314
+ echo 0 ./test/abc3
0 ./test/abc3
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 1314
0 1314
+ echo 0 ./test/abcparent
0 ./test/abcparent
+ (( a++ ))
+ echo 0 1314
0 1314
```

Comment: Shell variables do not maintain their values across different invocations of the shell, so what you're doing will never work.  Try piping `find`'s output to `wc -l` to count the lines of output.

Comment: I used that in past, it was working , but I thing I forget  something

Comment: @KyleJones I am doing count and print in same shell invocation

Comment: @Rahul: Kyle is right, and no you're not doing everything in the same shell: `xargs -n1` will invoke one `bash` shell for each line.

Comment: hmmmm , but in my past experience , it was working

Comment: @Mat I have added one example with `pid`

Comment: @Rahul: `-n1` makes all the difference. (Also note that even in the second case, if there is too much input, you'll get multiple shells.)

Comment: No sir same output with `-L` and `-n`

Comment: Multiple shell means different pid , but it's showing same pid using `echo $$`

Comment: @Mat & Kyle Jones  thanks ,  You are Correct , I was Wrong . Yes, it was single quotes mistake

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your variables are being expanded by bash before find is executed. Because of this `$a` is expanded to 0, `$$` is expanded to the PID of your (login) shell, so the command that is executed by `bash -xc` is actually:

```
echo 0 {} ;((a++)) ; echo 0 1314
```

Here `{}` is replaced by xargs with the result from `find` and the value of `$a` is postincremented, but never printed. Try escaping the variables (as in `\$a`), or even better, putting the `bash -xc` arguments in single quotes (`'`) instead of double quotes (`"`) to see that it works.

You will also notice that the other commenters are correct, `xargs -n1` (or with `-I{}`) executes a new shell for each argument, therefore incrementing `$a` will not work - the incremented value will not be visible to the next invocation of the `bash -xc` command.

Comment: Yes, it was single quotes mistake