# Get number of files in each directory

Tags: shell-script, ls

I have a directory with a very large number of subdirectories (~800) that were generated programmatically. I want to get a count of the number of files in each of these subdirectories to check for anomalies (if the code broke on a run then some of the files will be missing). What's a quick way to do this? The sort of output I'm looking for is:

```
Name_of_Folder_1 [# of files in Folder 1]   
Name_of_Folder_2 [# of files in Folder 2]
...
```

Comment: It's rarely used, but `diff` will happily report the differences between folders.  `diff folder1 folder2`.

Comment: See also [How can I get a count of files in a directory using the command line?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/1125) and there are more related questions if you take the time to search the site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you have no spaces in your directory names:

```
for dir in $(find . -type d); do
    echo "${dir}: $(find ${dir} -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l)"
done
```

Comment: see also: [Get recursive file count](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/219752/get-recursive-file-count-like-du-but-number-of-files-instead-of-size/219774#219774)

Comment: How to process files with spaces?

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the count of files in each subdirectory of the current directory, dealing with any strange file names (with gnu find).

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type f -printf "%h\0" | uniq -zc | tr '\0' '\n'
```